# I have following case when statement in SQL which was joined multiple tables. How can i covert this into power bi DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

case when A.status = 'ACTIVATED' and m.caller is not null then 'ACTIVE'
when A.status = 'ACTIVATED' and m.caller is null and n.callingparty is not null then
'AINACTIVE'
when A.status = 'ACTIVATED' and m.caller is null and n.caller is null then
'NO_USAGE'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join itself should be resolved by correct relationship in your model inside powerbi.

then write your measure as:

```
MyMeasureName =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    A[Status] = "ACTIVATED"
        && NOT ( ISBLANK ( M[Caller] ) ), "ACTIVE",
    A[Status] = "ACTIVATED"
        && ISBLANK ( M[Caller] )
        && NOT ( ISBLANK ( N[Callingparty] ) ), "AINACTIVE",
    A[Status] = "ACTIVATED"
        && ISBLANK ( M[Caller] )
        && ISBLANK ( N[Callingparty] ), "NO_USAGE",
    "Label for ELSE"
)
```